# How to extend AspNetUserLogin in ASP .Net Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

When user is logged in using external login provider such as **facebook** or **twitter** I want to save his `ExternalIdentity.Name` to the database to display on his user details page.

What I have now:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    var loginInfo = AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfo();
    if (loginInfo == null)
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { message = "LinkLoginError" });

    // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
    var result = SignInManager.ExternalSignIn(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
    ...
}
```

How can I extend/modify/override `SignInManager.ExternalSignIn` method to save `loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Name` to `dbo.AspNetUserLogins` table ?